# how to use 8 bits from 32 bit array of unsigned/signed bits

Tags: vhdl

I have defined an array

```
type stream_pix_rx is array(59 downto 0) of signed(31 downto 0);
signal pix_32_width : stream_pix_rx := (others => "00000000000000000000000000000000");
```

I am receiving 32 bits per clock at pix_32_width.

I want to use the all the four slots of 8 bits separately.I have another array of 8 bits:

```
type pix_rx is array(239 downto 0) of signed(8 downto 0);
signal pix_8_width : pix_rx := (others => "00000000");

I want to put pix_8_width(i) <= pix_32_width(j(first 8 bits));
then pix_8_width(i+1) <= pix_32_width(j(next 8 bits));
```

and so on.

Edit_ADD: 
I am receiving the 32 bit stream serially at every clock cycle or event so whenever I receive a 32 bit (after one event) I want to put it in pix_8_width( 0 to 3). and when I receive the next 32 bit stream I want to put it in pix_8_width(4 to 7) and so on. 
And when my 60th 32 bits are done I want to receive them in 1st 32 bit stream and put it in pix_8_width(0 to 3) and so on...
How can i do it ?

will simple this sort of thing work ?

```
pix_32_width(i) <= unsigned(S_AXIS_TDATA);
pix_8_width(4*i to 4*i+3) <= pix_32_width(i);
i <= i + 1;
```

To see the bigger picture of the thing which I am trying to achieve: 
I have asked a question 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109359/where-is-the-pixel-data-in-xilinx-axi-video-dma-ip-to-apply-a-sobel-filter-on
This has more details.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the question, do you mean you want all 60 32-bit words mapped to the 240 bytes at once, or just a single 32 bit word mapped to 4 bytes?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson does my Edit_ADD clarify that what exactly I want ?

Comment: Wouldn't the method be same whether do it for all the bits or for one slot of 32 bit to 8 bit ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're translating from one array representation to another with no intervening logic you can implement this as a conversion function:

```vhdl
function conv_32_to_8(p32: stream_pix_rx) return pix_rx is
  variable p8 : pix_rx;
begin
  for i in p32'range loop
    for j in 0 to 3 loop
      p8(i*4 + j) := p32(i)((j+1)*8 - 1 downto j*8);
    end loop;
  end loop;

  return p8;
end function;
```

This function isolates the bytes in little-endian order. To wire it for big-endian replace `p8(i*4 + j)` with `p8(i*4 + (3 - j))`.

To use this you can implement a continuous assignment to update `pix_8_width` whenever there is an event on `pix_32_width`:

```vhdl
pix_8_width <= conv_32_to_8(pix_32_width);
```

You can also invoke it from within a process if you want to control when the conversion is done.

Finally. You can simplify your array initialization by using `(others => (others => '0'))`. That saves you the trouble of trying to type in the right number of zeros for the inner arrays.

Comment: Two things.  Is it synthesizable?  What are you doing proposing passing an array of an array type and returning another?  Think of the poor stack.

Comment: Yes it synthesizes. The OP asked to move data from one array to another. You can't do that in VHDL without moving things around. Moreover, this isn't software. One is either simulating this code, in which case they are paying a performance penalty for running a simulation kernel anyway, or they are synthesizing to hardware which produces a wiring of nets with zero overhead. In complex simulations micro-optimizations for speed matter but there is no point worrying about that until the simulations run too long. The software principal of avoiding premature optimization does apply in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it and reply soon. Thanks a lot.  Also to see the bigger picture of this part you can look here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109359/where-is-the-pixel-data-in-xilinx-axi-video-dma-ip-to-apply-a-sobel-filter-on

Answer (score 1):

Your Edit_ADD implies a single array type:

> I am receiving the 32 bit stream serially at every clock cycle or
>   event so whenever I receive a 32 bit (after one event) I want to put
>   it in pix_8_width( 0 to 3). and when I receive the next 32 bit stream
>   I want to put it in pix_8_width(4 to 7) and so on. And when my 60th 32
>   bits are done I want to receive them in 1st 32 bit stream and put it
>   in pix_8_width(0 to 3) and so on... ***How can i do it*** ?

***emphasis added***

It sounds like a ring buffer.

For a memory you never have to access the full array from either write side or read side at the same time.  The memory array can be one type or the other.  You don't need a union between the two. You can either convert on the input side or the output side.

This example shows a memory could be organized in your pixel_rx array type:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity pix_ringbuff is
    port (
        clk:            in      std_logic;
        reset_n:        in      std_logic;
        pixel32w:       in      signed (31 downto 0);
        wrptr:          in      unsigned(5 downto 0);
        wr_en:          in      std_logic;
        rdptr:          in      unsigned(7 downto 0);
        pixel8w:        out     signed (7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture fum of pix_ringbuff is

    -- The memory array:

    type pix_rx is array(239 downto 0) of signed(7 downto 0);
    signal pix_8_width : pix_rx := (others => (others => '0'));

begin

WRITE:
    process(clk, reset_n)
        variable wrt_ptr:  natural range 0 to 239;
    begin

        if reset_n = '0' then
            pix_8_width <= (others => (others => '0'));
        elsif rising_edge(clk) and wr_en ='1' then
            wrt_ptr := to_integer(wrptr) * 4;
            pix_8_width(wrt_ptr)     <= pixel32w(31 downto 24);
            pix_8_width(wrt_ptr + 1) <= pixel32w(23 downto 16);
            pix_8_width(wrt_ptr + 2) <= pixel32w(15 downto 8);
            pix_8_width(wrt_ptr + 3) <= pixel32w(7 downto 0);
        end if;
    end process;

READ:
    process (rdptr, pix_8_width)
    begin
        pixel8w <= pix_8_width(to_integer(rdptr));
    end process;

end architecture;
```

What's missing is any logic for signaling an impending rollover, empty status, high or low water mark for throttling.  Those would be supra to the memory as are the pointers (counters), which are shown as unsigned seeing you used signed for pixel data.

Note all 4 pixels are written in one clock.  The byte Endian order matches your desired assignment:

```
pix_8_width(4*i to 4*i+3) <= pix_32_width(i);
```

And this doesn't work because the type on one side is pix_rx while on the other the type is stream_pix_rx.

Using a target aggregate:

```
        (pix_8_width(i*4),   pix_8_width(i*4+1),
         pix_8_width(i*4+2), pix_8_width(i*4+3)) <= 
                    pixel32'(
                        pixel32w(31 downto 24), 
                        pixel32w(23 downto 16),
                        pixel32w(15 downto 8),  
                        pixel32w(7 downto 0)
                    );
```

shouldn't work, the target aggregate elements aren't static.  IEEE Std 1076-1993 8.4 Signal assignment statement (-2008, 10.5/10.5.2.1):

> If the target of the signal assignment statement is in the form of an
>   aggregate, then the type of the aggregate must be determinable from
>   the context, excluding the aggregate itself but including the fact
>   that the type of the aggregate must be a composite type. The base type
>   of the value component of each transaction produced by a waveform
>   element on the right-hand side must be the same as the base type of
>   the aggregate. Furthermore, the expression in ***each element association
>   of the aggregate must be a locally static name*** that denotes a signal.
>   This form of signal assignment assigns slices or subelements of the
>   right-hand side values to the drivers associated with the signal named
>   as the corresponding slice or subelement of the aggregate.

***emphasis added***

An expression containing i declared as a variable or signal specifying slice range isn't locally static which means evaluated at analysis time.

You could assign one of your array types to the other with aggregates.  It would have to have every element listed and would take up a lot of source code in making the aggregates locally static.

There is something close to your original assignment:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity footest is
end entity;

architecture foo of footest is

    type stream_pix_rx is array(0 to 59) of signed(31 downto 0);
    signal pix_32_width : stream_pix_rx := 
                           (X"FEEDFACE",X"DEADBEEF",
                            X"00010203",X"04050607",others => (others => '0'));

    type pix_rx is array(0 to 239) of signed(7 downto 0);
    signal pix_8_width : pix_rx := (others => (others => '0'));

    signal i:  natural range 0 to 59 := 42;
begin
    pix_8_width (i*4 to i*4+3) <= 
            ( 
                pix_32_width(i)(31 downto 24),
                pix_32_width(i)(23 downto 16),
                pix_32_width(i)(15 downto 8),
                pix_32_width(i)(7 downto 0)
            );

STIM:
    process
    begin
        for j in stream_pix_rx'range loop
            if j = 59 then
                wait;
            else
                wait for 10 ns;
            end if;
            i <= j;
        end loop;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Which gives:

[image: right hand side aggregate]

The left hand side isn't an aggregate and isn't required to be static.  Note the array type ranges have been converted from descending to rising order to make the left hand side slice match your proposed signal assignment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look into it this weekend as I am working on something else at the moment but huge thanks. Also to see the bigger picture of this part you can look here (may be you can help me there also )http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109359/where-is-the-pixel-data-in-xilinx-axi-video-dma-ip-to-apply-a-sobel-filter-on

Comment: I mean this whole question which I have asked here is for the following task:  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109359/where-is-the-pixel-data-in-xilinx-axi-video-dma-ip-to-apply-a-sobel-filter-on So can you verify that whatever I asked here is correct or not. I guess 32 bits are coming VDMA block and then I am which has 4 pixel as I have 8bits per pixel so thats why I want to do the whole thing. I am also not sure that whatever I am trying is right approach to do the task or not. I have to write the sobel filter in the entity filter code.

Comment: I saw your stackexchange question, as well as S_AXIS_TDATA which said digital video. Are you planning on using three pixel buffers for three successive lines?  I imagine you're going to use Xilinx memories anyway.

Comment: I guess S_AXIS_TDATA is of 32 bits and my pixel size is 8 bits, so at one clk event I receiving 4 pixels. I am assuming there is a image stored in memory (for ex. assume 640*640 size matrix form written in memory). So S_AXIS_TDATA reads 32 bits (i.e 4 pixels) from the first row and first four column at one clk'event then in the next clk it reads the next 4 pixels and so on it goes to the 640th pixel and then it comes to the 2nd row, 1st four column reads 4 pixels(32 bits). So data is coming in this manner If I have understood things correctly. Now I have to apply sobel filter on this data...

Comment: and send the filtered 32 bits i.e 4 pixels in the M_AXIS(M_AXIS_TDATA) line. But the filter part is crucial as sobel requires surrounding pixel for for filtering one pixel. So to generate the first 8 bit filtered pixel I need to wait for first 640 pixel of first row and 2 pixels of 2nd row ( pixel size 8 bit) then calculate 1st filtered pixel. but the data is coming in 32bit slots and has to be sent it 32 bit slot (M_AXIS_TDATA) so I need to wait for 8 pixel of 2nd row and create 4 filtered pixel (8 bit*4 pixel = 32 bit = M_AXIS_TDATA) and send it..and this process has to be done till end.